# How can a function which prints be called repeatedly without returning the value of what was printed and without a for loop?

Tags: r, sapply

I recently wrote `for(i in 1:100){foo(i,bar)}` as the last line in a script. In this case, the last line of `foo` is a call to `print` and I definitely do not want to see the return values of `foo`. I only want the printing. This for loop works, but it feels unidiomatic to use a loop like this in R. Is there any more idiomatic way to achieve this? `foo` must take each `i in 1:100` individually before being called, so `foo(1:100,bar)` won't work.

`sapply(1:100,function(x) foo(x,bar))` seems more idiomatic, but it gives me both the return values of `foo` and its printing. I had considered using `do.call`, but having to use `as.list(1:100)` disgusted me. What are my alternatives?

Minimum example:

````
foo<-function(i,bar)
{
  print(paste0("alice",i,bar,collapse = ""))
}
for(i in 1:100){foo(i,"should've used cat")}
sapply(1:100,function(x) foo(x,"ugly output"))```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `invisible` in base R to suppress function return output:

```r
invisible(sapply(1:5, function(x) foo(x, "ugly")))

[1] "alice1ugly"
[1] "alice2ugly"
[1] "alice3ugly"
[1] "alice4ugly"
[1] "alice5ugly"
```

You can also use `purrr::walk` - it is like `sapply` in that it executes a function over iterated values, but wrapped with `invisible` by default:

```r
purrr::walk(1:100, ~foo(., "ugly"))
```

Comment: Am I to take it that there's no idiomatic way to do this without packages? I'm familiar with the tidyverse, but I didn't expect to need it for something so trivial.

Comment: See updates - there's also `invisible`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "idiomatic" here? Code aesthetics are subjective, so it might help to highlight what you're after (e.g. brevity, clarity, independence from packages).